# Is it possible to paint the window outside of the WindowProcedure function?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to paint a window when the program first loads, and then replace it with something else, but having a massive headache trying to get my head around how to do it.

This is what I've come up with so far but it does nothing:

```cpp
//main function in main.cpp

int main() {

    //initialise window

    window.introWindow();

    //rest of main function
}

//function defined in class source file:

void AppWindow::introWindow() {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    HDC hdc_x = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"intro_background.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    SelectObject(hdc_x, hBitmap);

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1200, 800, hdc_x, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"Roboto Th");
    DeleteDC(hdc_x);
    SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

    SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);

    std::wstring introductionText = L"Introducing...";

    TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, (LPCWSTR)introductionText.c_str(), strlen("Introducing..."));

    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
```

Comment: [BeginPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint): *"An application should not call `BeginPaint` except in response to a `WM_PAINT` message."* Though there's much more you'd need to worry about, like deleting DCs while still having resources selected into them, or never restoring DCs to the state in which they were handed to you. Start here: [Get Started with Win32 and C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows).

Comment: I was trying to avoid a massive amount of code in the `WindowProc` function however I think I might be able to do what I want by having an `OnPaint` function which holds an if statement and will paint the desired style if the program is in the "intro"

Comment: You could certainly trim down on the *"massive amount of code"* by moving code that's not related to painting out of the `WM_PAINT` handler, like loading the image data on every paint request. Never releasing the loaded image data certainly isn't very helpful either.

Comment: Call UpdateWindow() to force WM_PAINT to be sent, works even when the app is not yet pumping the message loop.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* paint your window outside of a WM_PAINT handler, but it's *not recommended*, and I suspect you might have problems with how that might interact with the modern desktop window manager.

To get your intro window to paint *before* starting the message loop [recommended]: Call [UpdateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow).  This will cause the WM_PAINT message to be sent for that Window without dispatching any other messages.  (You can probably use [RedrawWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-redrawwindow) if you set all the flags just right, but I think UpdateWindow is simpler, especially if you only need the client area painted.)

To paint your window outside of a WM_PAINT handler [not recommended]:  Do *not* use BeginPaint/EndPaint.  Instead, call [GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc), issue your drawing commands, and then call [ReleaseDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc).  That won't validate the parts of the window you paint, so you'll probably get a redundant WM_PAINT a moment later.  You can try to manually validate regions you paint, but it's really best to put all the painting in the WM_PAINT handler and just use UpdateWindow.  Also remember that, when painting yourself, you will not get a WM_ERASEBKGND message, so your painting code should not assume the background has already been drawn with the background brush.

Nowadays, the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) redirects all your GDI painting to offscreen buffers and then copies them to textures in the graphics card.  It has a good understanding of the normal WM_PAINT process so that method will almost certainly result in the textures being updated in a correct and timely manner.  Painting that happens outside WM_PAINT *may* not be reliably detected in a timely manner.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using InvalidateRect. That forces a WM_PAINT message. W.

Comment: Putting my code within a switch that reacts to `WM_PAINT` works, I wanted to avoid a load of code in my `WindowProc` function

Comment: *load of code in my WindowProc function* - this is what ?

Comment: If you're asking what I mean, I'm saying that my `WindowProc` function would become very long if I included all of the possibilities that it might be painted along with all of the possible key press instructions, etc. I'm proposing that I create a function elsewhere and call it following the `WM_PAINT` message

Comment: `InvalidateRect` doesn't *force* a `WM_PAINT` message. It does what it's function name implies: It adds a rectangular region to the currently invalidated region.

Comment: @askman; "I'm proposing that I create a function elsewhere" -- Yes, this is great for code organization.  "and call it following the WM_PAINT message" -- You should actually call it from WindowProc when you receive `WM_PAINT`.  By having nothing inside the `case WM_PAINT` except `return PaintHelperFunction(hWnd, wParam, lParam);` you will keep your WindowProc nice and clean.